# Why does my vimeo video look bigger than the size set on the website?

Tags: css

I have the following video which looks extremely big on the website. Looks right on fiddle. What could be wrong here? Please guide. Thanks. [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kaL1Lfgc/). [Website](http://www.inspuratesystems.com/nayajeevan/).

```
<iframe src="//player.vimeo.com/video/117775232" width="500" height="375" frameborder="0" webkitallowfullscreen mozallowfullscreen allowfullscreen></iframe>
<p>
<a href="http://vimeo.com/117775232">NAYA JEEVAN in 90 Seconds</a> 
from <a href="http://vimeo.com/user36757895">Naya Jeevan</a> on <a href="https://vimeo.com">Vimeo</a>.
</p>
```

Comment: For one, the fiddle and the website are completely different. On fiddle you use iframe, on website html5 video player. That is really badly asked question. Secondly, as the answer below says, you have width and heoght set to 100% on all elements wrapped around the video, including video itself. What did you expect will happen?

Answer (score 2):

you have

```
width:100%
height:100%
```

on `.video`